# URL rewriting for two parameters using .htaccess page not found 404

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to write custom URL  for 2 parameters

```
http://localhost/htaccess/site-list-pune-pune/xcxc
htaccess is my application fordername
```

but i get this error **"Object not found!"**
may be i missing in last rule please help me 
here is my code :

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On     

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?name=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*)/single-page\.php\?name=([^&\s]+)&dd=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]     

# /htaccess/Movie.php?name=movie-name => /htaccess/movie-name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?name=([^&\s]+)&dd=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%2? [R,L]     


# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?name=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2&dd=([^&\s]+) [L,QSA]

# handle /htaccess/movie-name internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ single-page.php?name=$1&dd=([^&\s]+) [L,QSA]
```

internal url : `http://localhost/htaccess/single-page.php?name=pune-site-list-pune&dd=xcxc`

Comment: What should be internal URL handler for `http://localhost/htaccess/site-list-pune-pune/xcxc`? And is this .htaccess located inside `/htaccess/` folder?

Comment: htaccess is root folder and .htaccess is located in root directory

Comment: internal url : "http://localhost/htaccess/single-page.php?name=pune-site-list-pune&dd=xcxc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your last rule by this rule:

```
# handle /htaccess/movie-name internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ single-page.php?name=$1&dd=$2 [L,QSA]
```

`([^&\s]+)` cannot be used in replacement as this this regex to capture values in `RewriteCond`.